# Set 2 input values in 2 select options at another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have 2 input fields on `home page` like this:
[image: 2 input fields on <code>home page</code>]

And there is 2 select options at `create page` Like this:
[image: 2 select options at <code>create page</code>]

When I enter relative values in those input fields
[image: relative values]

and click on create button, the `create page` load and the values of input fields set on select options Like this:

[image: values of input fields set on select]

> But here is a hard part of this question

I used a custom theme of WordPress and on create page all fields are created by dynamically ... so I don't get it and I have no code to display.

But I am showing you the code by **inspect element** so you can figure out:

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="tab-cont ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
   <fieldset class="fieldset-auto_type one_fourth">
      <label for="auto_type">Select Vehicle Maker<i class="icon-help-circled-1 tooltip"></i>
      </label>
      <div class="field">
         <select name="auto_type" id="auto_type" class="valid">
            <option value="0" selected="true">Select A Maker From The List</option>
            <option value="16">Alfa Romeo</option>
            <option value="17">Audi</option>
            <option value="25">BMW</option>
            <option value="29">Citroen</option>
            <option value="46">Ferrari</option>
            <option value="47">Ford</option>
            <option value="55">Honda</option>
            <option value="61">Lamborghini</option>
         </select>
         <i class="icon-angle-down select-icon"></i>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset class="fieldset-auto_category one_fourth">
      <label for="auto_category">Select Vehicle Model<i class="icon-help-circled-1 tooltip"></i>
      </label>
      <div class="field">
         <select name="auto_category" id="auto_category" required="required" data-msg-required="This field is required." class="valid">
            <option value="m3">M3 (3)</option>
            <option value="x5">X5 (1)</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Hope You will understand my question

Comment: If all fields are created dynamically then the HTML doesn't help us at all. You would pass the option and select it within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred solution is to use PHP, using [$_GET method](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to pass information from one page into another will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using only javascript 
you can in your first page set a variable like

```
localStorage.setItem("option", "value");
```

and in your second page get that like this :

```
   var myVar =  localStorage.getItem("option");
```

Now myVar will be equal to whatever value you setted in the first page which is in my case the string "Value"